# Configure routing table to switch between two interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, route

I have a Raspberry Pi (OS: Raspbian, debian based), that is connected to a router via Ethernet and a GSM module via USB.

I have a situation where I need to switch internet access between two interfaces based on availability.

If the Ethernet (`eth0`) does not have internet connectivity (but still connected to LAN), the GSM module (`ppp0`) needs to be used. If the internet connectivity is available on `eth0`, then `eth0` should be used.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
default         192.168.3.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

I want to know, is there any way if I can configure the routing in such a way that is is handled.

If not, then what command should I fire to switch different interface as primary (do I have to change metric?)

Comment: You need to explain the need to switch internet access based on availability. Kevin's answer contains a script that pings 8.8.8.8 and if fails changes the default route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a route failover which can be performed by running [this dual WAN failover script from Apsu found on Gist](https://gist.github.com/Apsu/5021255).

Answer (score 0):

Show your routes by `ip route` instead of `route` : it is deprecated (like netstat and ifconfig).

You can change the metric with the `ip route change 0.0.0.0/0 dev ppp0 metric 100`.

But I don't know how you can automate this.